# how to prepare data to learn a bayesian network

Tags: weka

My data is a 19*793 matrix, and I want to learn the structure of bayesian network use my data in weka. I got some trouble, my data is only speed of freeway segments, it seems that my weka can't deal with it. How can cope with it?

Comment: What's the error message Weka gives you?

Comment: Can't not handle numeric class, but I don't need do classification so there is no label in my data, it just has the value of 19 variable in different time. Maybe I don't understand bayesian networt well. What I really want is to learn the structure from the data and so I can see some casual relationship between these nodes, what else should I do? Thx. I can send you the data if it's necessary.

Comment: If you want to use the Bayesian network in Weka, you need to discretise the variable you want to predict. If you only have a few different values, you may be able to use them as categories, otherwise you'd have to split it up into intervals.

Comment: I have discretised the data, it just doesn't learn the structure for me. I think you can help only if I send you my data.

Comment: Me doing it is not going to help your understanding. What do you mean by "doesn't learn the structure"?

Comment: Weka will always ask me to choose to an attribute as the class, but I think I don't need to classify these nodes. So I don't know how to preprocess the data. I need to learn a bn has 19 nodes, the format is as follows: 85.938,88.5,84.407,82.5,78.79,75.522,73.077,79.412,81.127             this is one vector, and I have 19 such vectors and nothing else. Can I use this data to learn a bn ? I am just a beginner of Data Mining

Comment: The class attribute would be the one you want to predict, i.e. the output variable of your Bayesian network.

Comment: Maybe I don't even understand what a bn can do.